# How to give layout width as double value in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to set layout width as float value programmatically. But it accept only int value.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layoutParams.width = 200.75; // Here I am getting error.
```

But if I set by xml I am able to give float value.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="200.75dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

But not able to set programmatically. Please let me some idea to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DP (DIPs) are not pixels and "*layoutParams.width=*" requires Pixels.

200.75dp is not equal to 200.75px because it's Display Density dependant.
200.75dp could be more than 600px on some display.

You can convert PX in DP and vice-versa using simple methods (please search online).
However an internal conversion and Math.round() is done when "layout_width="200.75dp"" is executed in Runtime, and you can simulate it using appropriated conversion methods.